# Code requirements for lights mounted horizontally?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have a couple of lights in the basement that are mounted "naked" and horizontally.  Just would like to know if there is any restriction on doing that, e.g. height of the fixture?

[image: pic of luminaire]

Comment: What type of fixture and lamp?

Comment: Honestly I would replace that porcelain base with a receptacle and plug fluorescent lights into those.  And by "fluorescent" I mean lights 2-4 feet long that use any technology you please.  Those are horrible - you inevitably end up hitting it with your head or stuff you're moving, plunging the room into darkness while getting shocked too half the time.

Answer (score 1):

While there is code that does NOT permit bare incandescent bulbs in closets and hanging fixtures over a shower zone, unfinished basements are not on the list.  As suggested by Harper, fluorescent lights are a nice "work" light.